# Airflow: How to Load an XML File to BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, airflow

I am trying to write an Airflow DAG, which will load an `.XML` file to BigQuery using a Python method, but I believe that it needs to be converted into `.json` for it to work.

I have written the following code to convert an `.XML` file to `.json`, but I am unsure if this is correct, and how I can write a Python method to achieve this:

```
import json, xmltodict

def load_xml_to_bq():
    
with open("xml_file.xml") as xml_file:
    data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
    xml_file.close()
json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
with open("data.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_data)
        json_file.close()
```

Additionally, does the `.XML` file need to be loaded from a GCS Bucket for it to be inserted into BigQuery?

Furthermore, would the following code need to be added to my function for the `.XML` to be inserted into BigQuery?

```
    client = bigquery.Client()
    client.insert_rows_json(f'{dataset}.{table}', dec_sale_list)
```

Thanks - any help on how to accomplish this would be helpful; I feel that I have some of the correct concepts, but I am not sure what I need to add/remove to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the 2 following solutions.

**Solution 1 :**

- `PythonOperator` to transform your xml file to json with pure `Python` code and a lib called `xmltodict`
- Then use `GCSToBigqueryOperator` from the `Json` file to `Bigquery`

```py
dags_folder = os.getenv("DAGS_FOLDER")
xml_file_path_gcs = f'{dags_folder}/your_xml_file.xml'

def transform_xml_file_to_json():
    import json, xmltodict
    from google.cloud import storage

    with open(xml_file_path_gcs) as xml_file:
        data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
        xml_file.close()

    json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket("your-bucket")
    blob = bucket.blob('your_file.json')
    blob.upload_from_string(data=json.dumps(json_data), content_type='application/json')

with airflow.DAG(
        "dag",
        default_args=default_dag_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    xml_to_json = PythonOperator(
        task_id="transform_xml_to_json",
        python_callable=transform_xml_file_to_json
    )

    gcs_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
       task_id="gcs_to_bq",
       bucket="your-bucket",
       source_objects=['*.json'],
       destination_project_dataset_table="your_table",
       schema_object=f"dags/schema/creditsafe/{data_type}.json",
       source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
    ....,
   )

   xml_to_json >> gcs_to_bq
```

- The first operator transforms the xml to json file with the [xmltodict lib](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) and upload the json file to `GCS` with [Python client](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)
- The second operator loads the json file to `BigQuery`

**Solution 2 :**

All the work in the `PythonOperator` :

- Load the XML file
- Transform it to list of `Dicts`
- Use `Python` client and `insert_rows` method

```py
dags_folder = os.getenv("DAGS_FOLDER")
xml_file_path_gcs = f'{dags_folder}/your_xml_file.xml'

def load_xml_file_to_bq():
    import json, xmltodict
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    with open(xml_file_path_gcs) as xml_file:
        data_dicts = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
        xml_file.close()
    
    # Check if you have to transform data_dicts to the expected list of Dict. A Dict need to match exactly with the schema of the BQ table
    client = bigquery.Client()
    client.insert_rows_json('dataset.table', data_dicts)


with airflow.DAG(
        "dag",
        default_args=default_dag_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    load_xml_file_to_bq = PythonOperator(
        task_id="load_xml_file_to_bq",
        python_callable=load_xml_file_to_bq
    )

    load_xml_file_to_bq
```

Check if you have to transform `data_dicts` to the expected list of `Dict`. A `Dict` in the list needs to match exactly with the schema of the `BigQuery` table.

You have to be carreful, if your xml file is too big, it's not recommended to load heavy elements in a node.

Comment: OK, thanks for this - it makes sense. But, if I wanted to load the .XML file from a GCS Bucket, how would I do that? Or, do I just put the GCS Bucket location with the file here? ```with open("xml_file.xml") as xml_file:```

Comment: I edited my answer to show you, how to load file from `GCS` in `Airflow/Composer`. You have to use the `Composer` `dag folder` : `{composer_bucket}/dags/your_file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some online tools to verify the JSON output generated from xml looks ok(https://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson)

for example below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <customers>
 <customer id="55000">
    <name>Charter Group</name>
    <address>
        <street>100 Main</street>
        <city>Framingham</city>
        <state>MA</state>
        <zip>01701</zip>
    </address>
    <address>
        <street>720 Prospect</street>
        <city>Framingham</city>
        <state>MA</state>
        <zip>01701</zip>
    </address>
    <address>
        <street>120 Ridge</street>
        <state>MA</state>
        <zip>01760</zip>
    </address>
</customer>
</customers>
```

will generate JSON in this format

```
{
"customers": {
    "customer": {
    "-id": "55000",
    "name": "Charter Group",
    "address": [
        {
        "street": "100 Main",
        "city": "Framingham",
        "state": "MA",
        "zip": "01701"
        },
        {
        "street": "720 Prospect",
        "city": "Framingham",
        "state": "MA",
        "zip": "01701"
        },
        {
        "street": "120 Ridge",
        "state": "MA",
        "zip": "01760"
        }
    ]
    }
}
}
```

There are multiple methods by which you can do the xml to Json conversion in Python. you can use xmltodict, xml.etree.ElementTree, minidom. The code performance will be different for different libraries. If it's a relatively small xml file then it's okay to use **xmltodict**. If the Xml file is too large then you need to consider running your Python Script from Compute engine as the conversion Process will be resource intensive. For this you can use Airflow Google Compute Engine Operators (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/howto/operator/gcp/compute.html) to Start,Stop your GCE instance.

You can specify the xml file path (if the file is present in GCS then the path becomes GCS Path where the file is present) in the Python Script. If you are using Airflow then you can use **GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator** (https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.7/howto/operator/gcp/gcs.html) to load the generated Json to BigQuery

To summarise

- Load file from GCS into python Script
- Dump the generated JSON file to GCS or upload the generated Json data (data in Python variable) from with the Python utility Script directly to BigQuery using the BQ Python API's available
- If you are saving the generated JSON file to GCS the use **GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator**  to load the data into BigQuery

I will share a Python snippet that will work (Basic Python Script for xml to JSON conversion)

```
    import json
    import xmltodict
    
    with open("xml_file.xml") as xml_file:
    
    data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_file.read())
    json_data = json.dumps(data_dict)
    
    with open("data.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(json_data)
        json_file.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer; it has really helped me. Though, for the three steps you have mentioned, is there an example on this? I am new to Airflow, so it would be clearer if there was an example to refer to.

Comment: Also, is the Python snippet loading a file from GCS into a Python script?

Comment: No the Python Script isn't loading XML from GCS. I don't have an Airflow setup at the moment. Are you using Google Cloud Composer to author your DAGs.

Comment: You need to use Airflow Operators to do this task. What you need to do is write a DAG that will use PythonOperator and then create a function to do XML to JSON conversion and then invoke this function from PythonOperator.

 `python_task = PythonOperator(task_id='python_task', python_callable=my_conversion_function, dag=dag_python)`

Comment: I am using Composer as part of the free tier - this is just for a personal project to learn.